# Show and Hide a <iframe> with a toggle using ":checked"

Tags: javascript, html, function, toggle, checked

I got stuck with the JS. I first had 2 buttons and the "onClick" function but i want to "upgrade" these now to the toggle.
With this JS the video show/hide function and the switch slide doesn't work.
I want to show the video when the switch is checked.

Can someone help me with the JS?

```js
function showVideo(){
$("#video").hide();
$("#cb1").click(function() {
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $("#video").show(300);
    } else {
        $("#video").hide(200);
    }
});
}
```

```css
.tgl {
  display: none;
}

.tgl + .tgl-btn {
  outline: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 4em;
  height: 2em;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
}

.tgl + .tgl-btn:after, .tgl + .tgl-btn:before {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  content: "";
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}

.tgl + .tgl-btn:after {
  left: 0;
}

.tgl + .tgl-btn:before {
  display: none;
}

.tgl:onClick + .tgl-btn:after {
  left: 50%;
}

.tgl-light + .tgl-btn {
  background: #f0f0f0;
  border-radius: 2em;
  padding: 2px;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
  transition: all .4s ease;
}

.tgl-light + .tgl-btn:after {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
  transition: all .2s ease;
}

.tgl-light:checked + .tgl-btn {
  background: #9FD6AE;
}
```

```html
<input class="tgl tgl-light" id="cb1" type="checkbox"/>
<label class="tgl-btn" for="cb1"></label>

<iframe id="video" style='width:360px; height: 190px; border: none' src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/owsfdh4gxyc"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just don't include the `("#cb1").click(...` inside a function. `showVideo()` is actually never called anywhere, so the event handlers aren't added:

```js
$("#video").hide();
$("#cb1").click(function() {
    console.log($(this).is(":checked"));
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $("#video").show(300);
    } else {
        $("#video").hide(200);
    }
});
```

```css
.tgl {
  display: none;
}

.tgl + .tgl-btn {
  outline: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 4em;
  height: 2em;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
}

.tgl + .tgl-btn:after, .tgl + .tgl-btn:before {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  content: "";
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}

.tgl + .tgl-btn:after {
  left: 0;
}

.tgl + .tgl-btn:before {
  display: none;
}

.tgl:onClick + .tgl-btn:after {
  left: 50%;
}

.tgl-light + .tgl-btn {
  background: #f0f0f0;
  border-radius: 2em;
  padding: 2px;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
  transition: all .4s ease;
}

.tgl-light + .tgl-btn:after {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
  transition: all .2s ease;
}

.tgl-light:checked + .tgl-btn {
  background: #9FD6AE;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="tgl tgl-light" id="cb1" type="checkbox"/>
<label class="tgl-btn" for="cb1"></label>

<iframe id="video" style='width:360px; height: 190px; border: none' src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/owsfdh4gxyc"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

You was so close, no need for the function just put the event outside of it and it will work.

I suggest the use of `toggle()` instead conditional `hide()/show()` in your case, like :

```
$("#cb1").click(function() {
   $("#video").toggle(300);
});
```

```js
$("#video").hide();

$("#cb1").click(function() {
   $("#video").toggle(300);
});
```

```css
.tgl {
  display: none;
}

.tgl+.tgl-btn {
  outline: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 4em;
  height: 2em;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.tgl+.tgl-btn:after,
.tgl+.tgl-btn:before {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  content: "";
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}

.tgl+.tgl-btn:after {
  left: 0;
}

.tgl+.tgl-btn:before {
  display: none;
}

.tgl:onClick+.tgl-btn:after {
  left: 50%;
}

.tgl-light+.tgl-btn {
  background: #f0f0f0;
  border-radius: 2em;
  padding: 2px;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
  transition: all .4s ease;
}

.tgl-light+.tgl-btn:after {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
  transition: all .2s ease;
}

.tgl-light:checked+.tgl-btn {
  background: #9FD6AE;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="tgl tgl-light" id="cb1" type="checkbox" />
<label class="tgl-btn" for="cb1"></label>

<iframe id="video" style='width:360px; height: 190px; border: none' src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/owsfdh4gxyc"></iframe>
```